# Как создать массив с отобранными элементами?

Tags: массивы

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i = i + 2) {
                            var Result = new Array();   
                            Result.push(array1[i]);
                            console.log(Result);
                    };
```

Подскажите, почему после выборки элементов из массива array1 и добавления их в массив Result методом push создается массив с одним элементом (то есть Result имеет длину всего в один элемент, где уже находится вся выборка array1[i]). Нужно создать массив Result с отобранными элементами array1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Solomko](/users/24286/solomko) потому что Result пересоздается на каждой итерации

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i = i + 2) { // Result == [0]
    var Result = new Array(); // Result == []
    Result.push(array1[i]); // Result == [2]
    console.log(Result);
};
```

Вам, естественно, нужно инициализировать массив до самого цикла

```
var Result = new Array(); 
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i = i + 2) {
    Result.push(array1[i]);
    console.log(Result);
};
```